# Sharepoint Workflow - Send Email from approval task form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

In my reusable workflow, I have added an approval action. Everything works perfectly. What I want is - When approver comes to approval form, he should be able to send notification email to the initiator (From that form) that he has started working on that document.

What I have tried - I have added a button clicking on which will submit the form to initiator. Screenshot:

[image]

But it fails. possible reason - when I create a data connection in workflow's infopath form to submit form as email, I am getting following warning

[image]

I also tried to update status field and wait for it to changes in workflow and send an email from sp designer workflow. it didn't work.

Please help or suggest any other possible way to achieve this functionality (Send Email from approval task form to initiator).

Comment: Error message? Code that sends the mail?

Comment: There is no code involved. I am using infopath's 'submit form as email' data connection to submit this as email to initiator. Sharepoint online gives following error: "The form cannot be submitted because of an error.
Click OK to resume filling out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors." no details available.except the corelation id

Comment: Do normal mails (notifications) from sharepoint work? Is the email service configured?

Comment: Yes, other mails are going out fine. It's sharepoint 2013 online.

Comment: Did you try and change the security level to Restricted? Is there any additional info about the error in the ULS log?